# glutWarpPointer() not working while application is active

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, glut

My problem is the screen will no longer rotate while my mouse is in screen. Only when the application is no longer active.

if I take out these warp pointers then it starts working again.

Here is my mouse update:

```
mouse.x = x;
mouse.y = y;

if (x > screen.x/2)
{
    player.angle -= 0.05f;
    player.lx = sin(player.angle);
    player.lz = -cos(player.angle);
    glutWarpPointer(screen.x/2,screen.y/2);
}
else if (x < screen.x/2)
{
    player.angle += 0.05f;
    //if (player.vertAngle < 0)
        //player.vertAngle = 0;
    player.lx = sin(player.angle);
    player.lz = -cos(player.angle);
    glutWarpPointer(screen.x/2,screen.y/2);
}
if (y < screen.y/2)
{
    player.vertAngle += 0.05f;
    player.ly = sin(player.vertAngle);
    glutWarpPointer(screen.x/2,screen.y/2);
}
else if (y > screen.y/2)
{
    player.vertAngle -= 0.05f;
    //if (player.vertAngle > 360)
        //player.vertAngle = 360;
    player.ly = sin(player.vertAngle);
    glutWarpPointer(screen.x/2,screen.y/2);
}
```

Comment: This probably doesn't help but, but a better way to do your player rotation is `player.angle = x - screen.x/2`. This is better, because the way you have it now, your player always turns the same amount regardless of whether the mouse moves 1 pixel or 100 pixels. This fixes that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a flag to ignore the extra motion event that `glutWarpPointer()` generates:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool capture = false;
void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    if( key == 'z' )
    {
        capture = !capture;
    }
}

void passiveMotion( int x, int y )
{
    static bool warped = false;
    if( warped )
    {
        warped = false;
        return;
    }

    if( capture )
    {
        warped = true;
        int w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
        int h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
        glutWarpPointer( w / 2, h / 2 );

        int dx = ( w / 2 ) - x;
        int dy = ( h / 2 ) - y;
        cout << dx << " " << dy << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << x << " " << y << endl;
    }
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
    glutCreateWindow( "GLUT" );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );
    glutPassiveMotionFunc( passiveMotion );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```